# JavaScript regex to find special words not wrapped in a tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex to search a string and find words wrapped in curly braces that are not wrapped in a span tag with a specific attribute (data-placeholder).

Example text:

```
This is a test. Testing <span class="anything">{variable}</span> wrapped without the attribute, but this one <span data-placeholder="val">{variable}</span> is. The first should match, the second should not, and the last one should as well {variable}
```

The best I've come up with so far is:

```
/[^>]{(.)*}[^>]/g
```

But that has a few problems. There may or may not be text after the closing }, so that pattern does not match the last instance in the example text. It will also not match the first instance, I'm not sure how to write "match anything except this word" for the first part of the regex.

The goal is to convert instances of (note anything is literal):

```
{variable}
<span class="anything">{variable}</span>
```

To this (or):

```
<span data-placeholder="">{variable}</span>
<span data-placeholder="" class="anything">{variable}</span>
```

Without disrupting any existing instances that are already converted.

Thanks!

Edit: solved using a combination of DOM traversal and regex for textnodes. Thanks @jonathan-m and @frankiethekneeman!

Comment: Google "negative lookahead"

Comment: Regex is very unreliable for parsing html. Best practice: don't do it. Instead use a parser for HTML and then examine the contents of the tags. Regex IS reliable for contents.

Comment: You should really, honestly use a recursive method with an HTML Parser.  Not just because of "parsing HTML the cthulu way", but because it'll make your code more extensible, and easier to maintain.  Are you using any Javascript frameworks?  Is this server side code, or to be executed on a page somewhere?

Comment: Are these valid HTML documents you are trying to query?

Comment: Working on it- yes the string is part of the DOM. I'm doing the conversion in a few steps using a combination of jQuery selectors and regex.

1. jQuery to grab spans, check for attributes etc, this catches the more complete case and the content should be exactly {var}.

2. In the pure text cases I'm using a selector to grab each line, then stripping off the children to prevent matches under the node, then regex to look for {var} inside the text nodes.

When I have it fully working I'll reply again.

Comment: @Jonathan What are the {variable} and the <span...> following it contained in? Are they in another span, div, p, or body tag? if yes, which?

Comment: The div I'm searching has a series of p tags, inside those p tags is text and/or other tags. So {var} may be in the p, or there may be a span inside the p with {var} inside it, or there may be nested versions of either.

Comment: If you solved it and think that your solution might be helpful for others, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Solution (thanks again to @jonathan-m and @frankiethekneeman):

```
//remove any broken variables
variables = $( 'span[data-placeholder]', this.editor );
for ( i = 0, len = variables.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    if ( pp.arrayIndexOf( dict, variables[ i ].innerHTML ) == -1 ) {
        t = variables[ i ].childNodes[ 0 ];
        $( t ).unwrap( );
    }
}

//convert any variables already in a span tag
variables = $( 'span', this.editor );
for ( i = 0, len = variables.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    t = variables[ i ].innerHTML.match( /^{(.)*}$/ );

    if ( !variables[ i ].hasAttribute( 'data-placeholder' ) && t != null && pp.arrayIndexOf( dict, t[ 0 ] ) != -1 ) {
        variables[ i ].setAttribute( 'data-placeholder', this.getVariable( t[ 0 ] ) );
    }
}

//convert any variables in a text node
variables = $( 'p', this.editor );
for ( i = 0, len = variables.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    for ( j = 0, len2 = variables[ i ].childNodes.length; j < len2; j++ ) {
        if ( variables[ i ].childNodes[ j ].nodeType == 3 ) {
            t = variables[ i ].childNodes[ j ].data.match( /{(.)*}/ );

            if ( t != null && pp.arrayIndexOf( dict, t[ 0 ] ) != -1 ) {
                span = document.createElement( 'span' );
                span.setAttribute( 'data-placeholder', this.getVariable( t[ 0 ] ) );
                span.innerHTML = t[ 0 ];

                variables[ i ].replaceChild( span, variables[ i ].childNodes[ j ] );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Loop 1: In case a user has edited the text and turned a variable into something else, break the edited content out of its wrapper.

Loop 2: Check every span tag, if it already has data-placeholder ignore it, if not check its contents to see if its a variable.

Loop 3: Check every p tag, look for text nodes inside it that match a variable. If found, create a span and replace the text node with a wrapper.

Note: Just realized I haven't tested multiple occurrences in a text node, so that may not work with this code. Going to test now.

Comment: Your regexp is no good, try mine:  
`" here is a {variable} and a mustache } ".match( /{(.)*}/ )`  
`["{variable} and a mustache }", " "]`  
`" here is a {variable} and a mustache } ".match( /{[^}]+}/g )`  
`["{variable}"]`

Comment: Yes my original regex is matching too much, I'm using /{([^}]+)}/g now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Working in my Google Chrome directly on this question, I find following code a promising start in the JavaScript console:

### Code

```
nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('span');
nodeArray=[];
for (i=0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {nodeArray.push(nodeList[i]);}
nodeArray.filter(function(node) {return node.innerText.match(/{variable}/)});
```

Note how we select actual HTML elements based on the Document Object Model and then look for candidates based on their text content. Alternatively one could use .innerHTML, or actually manipulate document content via assignment to these properties.

### Result

```
[
<span class=​"str">​
"/span> wrapped without the attribute, but this one <span data-placeholder="val">{variable}</"
</span>​
, 
<span class=​"pln">​{variable}​</span>​
, 
<span class=​"pln">​{variable}​</span>​
, 
<span class=​"comment-copy">​
"@Jonathan What are the {variable} and the <span...> following it contained in? Are they in another span, div, p, or body tag? if yes, which?"
</span>​
, 
<span class=​"str">​/{variable}/​</span>​
]
```

[jQuery.contains](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) may also be interesting.